# Margin Animation?

Tags: windows-phone-7

If I want to create a animation which change a control margin, and I need to write C# code instead of use blend, how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you want to change the margin? what kind of animation are you focusing upon? However you may use `DoubleAnimation` and `StoryBoard` to create your animation. Please refer the link below for a start.

`http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Animations-in-depthndash-Overview-and-Getting-Started`